# How to avoid redefining default parameter with Python inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, constructor, default-parameters

For simple inheritance such as

```
class Base:
  def __init__(self, env: str = 'prod'):
    #...

class Derived(Base):
  def __init__(self, env: str = 'prod'):
    super().__init__(str)
```

How do I avoid redefining default constructor parameters in both classes? If I instantiate `Derived()` I do want `env` to default to `'prod'`, I just don't want to redefine the value in multiple classes. If I later decide that the default value should be something else (e.g. `'dev'`), then I would have to change all derived constructors.

I was thinking of something like

```
class Base:
  def __init__(self, env: str = 'prod'):
    #...

class Derived(Base):
  def __init__(self, env: str = None):
    if env is None:
      super().__init__()
    else:
      super().__init__(env)
```

or maybe defining the default value as a global constant in the base class? Either method seems overly complex. What's the Pythonic way?

Comment: If the `__init__` in the derived class is the same as in the base class, just don't redefine it in `Derived`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a class variable.

```
class Base:
    DEFAULT_ENV = "prod"
    def __init__(self, env=None):
        if env is None:
            env = self.DEFAULT_ENV
        # ...
```

If you want to have a different default env in a subclass, just override `DEFAULT_ENV` in that class. If you want to change your default env for all classes that do not override it, changing `DEFAULT_ENV` in `Base` will work.

Also redifining `__init__` in a subclass is optional in Python so if you don't want `__init__` in your subclasses to implement different behavior from `Base` just ommit it in subclasses. Another advantage of having your default env in a class variable is that if you want to change only that in a subclass you can override the class variable and you do not have to redifine `__init__` in the child !

EDIT: if you feel that env determination might require some funny business (like testing for environment variables, or anything else in your app) later on, you might want to wrap `default_env` in a property:

```
class Base:
    DEFAULT_ENV = "prod"
    def __init__(self, env=None):
        if env is None:
            env = self.default_env
        # ...
    @property
    def default_env(self):
        return self.DEFAULT_ENV
```

That way later on you can implement the expected behaviour in the property getter.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that has its pros and cons could be to use kwargs. Something like:

```py
class Base:
  def __init__(self, env: str='prod'):
    #...

class Derived(Base):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
```